# Populate dropdown from two tables with differentiation between them

Tags: c#, sql, combobox

I am populating a combobox in C# & SQL.I have two tables to get data from them.

```
Table1

Id   CategoryName
 1    Salary
 2    Utility
 3    Other

Table2

Id   SubCategoryName   CatId
1     XYZ Salary         1
2     YY Salary          1
3      Car Exp           3
```

Now i want to show them all in a dropdown so that User select any of them and then i will save its Id.

How i will Know that selected Id is from `Table1` OR `Table2` ?

Comment: How do you want to know?  A combobox only has one ID property.  Do you want to create an artificial id system so that it will contain both the Table and the ID within the table?  Do you want to populate two variables?

Comment: This is what i asked what to do?I need to show both tables data in combonbox and also i want to get the selected id and save in db.The issue is either this id is from first table or second table?

Comment: If you only need to save the id in the db, what does it matter which table it came from?   Are you doing more than saving the id in the db?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to play around with fake id's. For example, you could create a new class with a new Id and map that new id to the tables manually. For example:

```
Class DisplayItem
Id 1 Name Salary
Id 2 Utility
Id 3 Other
Id 4 XYZ Salary
ID 5 Y Salary
Id 6 Car Exp
```

Then you will need code that looks like this

```
public int GetTableId(int DisplayItemId)
{
    if (DisplayItemId < 4)
         return 1;
    return 2;
}
```